# No Microsoft Identity Authentication Type for "Blazor Web App" Project Template?

Tags: blazor, project-template, .net-8.0

I'm running Visual Studio 2022 17.8 and have .NET 8.0.100 SDK (both are Release versions, I was never running Preview) installed but it seems the new "Blazor Web App" Project Template doesn't have Microsoft Identity as an Authentication Type?
[image: Project Configuration Window]

Did Microsoft release this template without support for this Authentication Type or have I missed something?

Comment: It is indeed missing, from the CLI as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons beyond my comprehension, this functionality is not available in this template for .NET 8 and is planned for .NET 9.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51202